# Error with Google_sign_in plugin in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I've been trying to fix this for a while now but I can't solve it.
When I use the google_sign_in plugin, I'm able to choose my account but it stops after that.

[image: SignIn]

But after clicking...
[image: After]

Giving me this error(the same) when I click continue:

E/flutter (28971): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Things I've done:

- I've searched for hours the error, the ApiException: 10, in Flutter and in Android in general.
- Adding a SHA1 key, I've followed multiple tutorials (each one is different one to another, which is really confusing).
- Downloaded the new JSON file.
- Flutter clean.
- Contemplated not using it.
- Asking here.

Right now I'm using:

- firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
- google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3

The app is in debug mode. I don't have an account to publish in the Google Store.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register your **fingerprint** `debug.keystore` in `firebase`,
you probably only registered an `release.keystore`:

show `debug.keystore` (linux):

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

source: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Internal App Sharing** to test Flutter builds on actual Android devices (like I am), there is **another App Signing certificate fingerprint** you need to add.

Find it using the left navigation of Google Play Console go to: **Developer Tools -> Internal App Sharing**

Select the **App Certificate** tab. Should look something like this:

[Google Play - Internal App Sharing - Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XaXr.png)

Copy the SHA1 key for your Internal test certificate and add it to the Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> [your Android app] -> SHA certificate fingerprints (use the button to Add fingerprint)

Download your updated google-services.json and update/add it in your android/app folder of your project.

This works with new users and existing users. I built the an appbundle (not APK) using `flutter build appbundle`

The above solution isn't documented anywhere by Google and I have not seen this solution elsewhere in the Flutter community. I came across this solution while poking around in the Google Play console after trying dozens of "fixes" that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my day, otherwise definitely, I had to do lifetime R&D for same.
This is what I was looking for.